# how to insert list of dicrionaries [{},{},{}] into postgres json[] type

Tags: python, json, postgresql

hi sorry if this has been asked before, but I have tried to search for the answer and couldn't find anything similar to what I'm having trouble with.

I have created a column in postgres table with type json[], and I would like to store list of dictionaries in it.

i tried to simply do json.dumps(list_of_dictionaries) but this didn't work. and here is the error message I got.

```
Error malformed array literal: 
*****between is result of json.dumps(list_of_dictionaries)*****
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if there is anything you would like me to provide to clear this up.

Comment: Each individual array element can be JSON, but the array itself can’t be. `[json.dumps(d) for d in list_of_dictionaries]` might be a start. How are you passing the value to PostgreSQL? A parameter with psycopg2?

Comment: yes using psycopg2. ```cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO table (item) VALUES (%s) """, data)``` something like this i will try what you suggested.

Comment: i'm getting a new error, Traceback (most recent call last):
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "column" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: ...020-04-23'::date,'2020-04-23T17:00:00'::timestamp,ARRAY['{"l...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
so i used Json from ``` from psycopg2.extras import Json``` to cast into json, then i get the same error.

Comment: ah! i changed data type to jsonb and now it's working! thanks! if you don't mind, can you put your comment as answer and I will mark it as answer? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the array as a list where its elements are `psycopg2.extras.Json`, like this:

```
[Json(d) for d in list_of_dictionaries]
```